# static variables empty when using dynamic loading of library

Tags: c++, dynamic-loading

I have this setup:

**ClassA.h - belongs to libA.dll**

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    static std::vector<std::string> getStrings();
    ~ClassA();
    static void addToVector(std::string s);
    static void setAddAllowed(bool addAllowed);
private:
    ClassA();
};

extern "C"
{
  extern void addToStrings(std::string s);
}
```

**ClassA.cpp**

```
#include<ClassA.h>
#include<vector>
static std::vector<std::string> strings;
static bool addAllowed = false;

std::vector<std::string> ClassA::getStrings()
{
    return strings;
}

void ClassA::addToVector(std::string s)
{
    if (addAllowed)
    {
        strings.push_back(s);
    }

}

void ClassA::setAddAllowed(bool add)
{
    addAllowed = add;

}

extern void addToStrings(std::string s)
{
    ClassA::addToVector(s);
}
```

**ClassB.h - belongs to libB.dll**

```
class ClassB
{
public:
    static void addString(std::string s);
};
```

**ClassB.cpp**

```
#include<ClassB.h>
#include<ClassA.h> //not present if libA is dynamically loaded.
void ClassB::addString(std::string s)
{
    addToStrings( s ); // problem if addToStrings is called with a function pointer obtained from dynamic loading of libA.dll - libB doesn't depend on libA actually.
}
```

**ClassC.h**

```
class ClassC
{
public:
    static void setAddAllowed(bool add);
};
```

**ClassC.cpp**

```
#include<ClassA.h>
#include<ClassC.h>
void ClassC::setAddAllowed(bool addAllowed)
{
    ClassA::setAddAllowed(addAllowed);
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    ClassB::addString("example1");
    ClassC::setAddAllowed( true );
    ClassB::addString("example2");
    ClassB::addString("example3");

    std::vector<std::string> v = ClassA::getStrings();
}
```

with this setup, every thing works fine, I could get the strings in `ClassA::getStrings()`. But the problem appears - the vector is empty, if I add the strings in ClassB using function pointer obtained from dynamically loaded dll of `libA`. I get the symbol of `extern function addToStrings` as function pointer and make a call. In that case, the vector `v` is empty.

Example code for loading libA and calling the function:

```
typedef void (*addToStringsFP) (std::string s);
addToStringsFP fp = NULL;
Handle libHandle = NULL;
libHandle = LoadImage("libA",0);
fp = (addToStringsFP)FindSymbol(libHandle,"addToStrings");
```

This is only to demonstrate how I am loading libA and calling the function pointer. LoadImage, FindSymbol are similar to [`dlopen(), dlsym()`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) - I can't post actual names.

What am I misunderstanding here ?

Comment: Can you post the code that doesnt work, rather than one, that does?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Updated the question.

Comment: Curious if `extern` void addToStrings(std::string s); should be `extern "C" void addToStrings(std::string s);` Maybe cpp is mangling the name?

Comment: @atomSmasher It is actually inside `extern "C"` I updated the code.

Comment: std::vector<std::string> & v = ClassA::getStrings(); How does this compile? ClassA::getStrings() doesn't return a reference.

Comment: Well, default value for addAllowed is false. Which prevents addition. Maybe try calling `setAddAllowed(true)`?

Comment: @atomSmasher you are right, but somehow MS Visual Studio allowed it to compile ! I didn't notice it. weird. Anyway updated the code.

Comment: I think I know the answer, when the dll is loaded dynamically it does in its own process (probably), the current process is different from that process is my guess.

Comment: @svasa: `when the dll is loaded dynamically it does in its own process` - no, that's definitely wrong: A dynamically loaded dll is always loaded into the process where the LoadLibrary (or equivalent) call is made from.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ok, it was just my guess, then what could be the reason why the vector is different when I use dynamically loaded dll. I debugged and saw that the address of vector is different in class B ( where dll is dynamically loaded ) from what is seen by other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

The `LoadImage` function that I am using is loading a new image into the process instead of looking at already loaded dlls first and then load. 
I had to use a different version of the `LoadImage` which loads the image that is currently in the process- basically a shared image. That solved the problem.

I thought it might be useful to someone who may have some problem albeit not much probable I think.